# Video, flash or... videos for HTML

Tags: jquery, html, flash, video, self

I'm not new to HTML, CSS, JS or PHP, I already made diff. web pages, but every time when I included a video from YouTube or from another external site, I always used iframe, or embed code. So, today I started to make my own personal page, and I want to know how to insert my own videos. I have two different web hosts, one for uploading videos and another for the webpage. So the stream (am I correct?) is coming from host#1, and host#2 is for web page.

I don't even know how to format or convert videos mpeg, avi to flv online (with my own page), but this is not why I made this post. Am I need to convert them into flv, to put videos on my page? What about the converted video quality (losing from quality)?

How can I make my own online video player?

Comment: There are plenty of good players you can use. No need to reinvent the wheel. http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DIVE INTO HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) has an excellent [article on HTML5 video](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html). You should read this article from A-Z (grab a coffee). It addresses almost all issues related to HTML5 videos including the reasons why you should be converting to HTML5 video, video formats, how to convert videos and how to add markup to your page to play those videos.

And in case you are wondering how to play the HTML5 videos, have a look at [HTML5 Video Player Comparison chart](http://praegnanz.de/html5video/). FYI, a HTML5 video player is a JavaScript wrapper over the browser's native HTML5 player which is supposed to provide skinning, API, events and flash fallback support.

Having said that, you do not need an HTML5 player at all if you do not care about custom skins, event handling, API etc. All you need is the "code" suggested by [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#video-code) (but you still need a SWF file capable of playing MP4 files).

Comment: HTML5 yes, but what if some people has older version browsers?

Comment: Good question, that is why I referred you to the chart. Notice that there is a column titled "flash fallback". A decent HTML5 player adds a flash fallback -- a little SWF file capable of playing H.264 (MP4) format videos. Go for a player that has a flash fallback option.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use Vimeo to upload my videos and they do all of the conversion and optimization for you and of course host the video on their servers.  When I load the videos on my own server, due to the bandwidth constraints and throughput, they quickly slow things down.

Comment: I need to use my own upload system.

Comment: And what if you do use the flash or mpeg route etc and a user browses to your site with an iPad/iPod or device which has no support for the video type? They couldn't see your videos... unless you use HTML5 methods and techniques by default.  This is another reason for Vimeo.

Comment: I include a statement for diff. OS and browsers. If browser supports HTML5 the video will be included with this way, if not... I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert a video file into another format, I would give this a try: [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)